# php resize image on upload

Tags: php, image

I got a form where the user is inserting some data and also uploading an image.

To deal with the image, I got the following code:

```
define("MAX_SIZE", "10000");
$errors = 0;
$image = $_FILES["fileField"]["name"];
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];
if($image){
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['fileField']['name']);
    $extension = strtolower(getExtension($filename));
    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")){
        echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
        $errors = 1;
    } else {
        $newname = "$product_cn.$extension";
        $size = filesize($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024){
            echo "You have exceeded the size limit";
            $errors = 1;
        }
        if($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" ){
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
        } else if($extension == "png"){
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
        } else {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
        }
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
        $newwidth = 60;
        $newheight = ($height/$width)*$newwidth;
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        $newwidth1 = 25;
        $newheight1 = ($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
        $tmp1 = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1, $newheight1);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp1, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth1, $newheight1, $width, $height);
        $filename = "../products_images/$newname";
        $filename1 = "../products_images/thumbs/$newname";
        imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100); // file name also indicates the folder where to save it to
        imagejpeg($tmp1, $filename1, 100);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($tmp1);
    }
}
```

getExtension function:

```
function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str, ".");
    if (!$i) { return ""; }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}
```

I've wrote some notation in the code since I'm not really familiar with those functions.

For some reason, it doesn't work. When I'm going to the folder "product_images" or "product_images/thumbs", I can't find any image uploaded.

Any idea what's wrong with my code? There should be 60px width image, and 25px width image.

Note: Variables that you don't know where they were declared such as `$product_cn` were declared before that block of code which works prefectly fine (tested). If you still want a glance at it, feel free to ask for the code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this library to manipulate the image while uploading. http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

Comment: WARNING: The script is under GPL, so you either need to buy commercial version ($15) or open your website sources under GPL.

Answer (score 55):

Here is another nice and easy solution:

```
$maxDim = 800;
$file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file_name );
if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
    $target_filename = $file_name;
    $ratio = $width/$height;
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $new_width = $maxDim;
        $new_height = $maxDim/$ratio;
    } else {
        $new_width = $maxDim*$ratio;
        $new_height = $maxDim;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file_name ) );
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
    imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
    imagedestroy( $src );
    imagepng( $dst, $target_filename ); // adjust format as needed
    imagedestroy( $dst );
}
```

Reference: [PHP resize image proportionally with max width or weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627476/php-resize-image-proportionally-with-max-width-or-weight)

Edit: Cleaned up and simplified the code a bit. Thanks @jan-mirus for your comment.

Comment: It works, but I'm confused - why do you extract the image dimensions twice?

Comment: This is fantastic. Though it's missing a very important line at the end: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $destinationFilePath);`

Comment: @jan-mirus It was bc the width and height vars were getting changed in the middle. It wasn't pretty and should be easier to read now.

Comment: Could somebody explain where the image file is sent to? I don't seem to be able to find it? I basically want to take a resized image and insert into a database. I'm imagining its $target_filename, but I've reached the limit of my knowlegde.

Comment: i have a question, why the position of the photo horizontal not vertical ?? i mean i take a picture vertical but the result is horizontal.

Answer (score 12):

// This was my example that I used to automatically resize every inserted photo to 100 by 50 pixel and image format to jpeg hope this helps too

```
if($result){
$maxDimW = 100;
$maxDimH = 50;
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] );
if ( $width > $maxDimW || $height > $maxDimH ) {
    $target_filename = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $fn = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $size = getimagesize( $fn );
    $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $width = $maxDimW;
        $height = $maxDimH/$ratio;
    } else {
        $width = $maxDimW*$ratio;
        $height = $maxDimH;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fn));
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1] );

    imagejpeg($dst, $target_filename); // adjust format as needed


}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],"pdf/".$_FILES['pdf']['name']);
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Best answer - no any library requires! move_uploaded_file - should be removed, as imagejpeg move the file to the new destination $target_filename

Comment: why do are $target_filename and $fn the same? why not just use one?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];  ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="something" class="uniForm">
    <input name="new_image" id="new_image" size="30" type="file" class="fileUpload" />
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="submitButton">Upload Image</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){              
          $imagename = $_FILES['new_image']['name'];
          $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
          $target = "images/".$imagename;
          $type=$_FILES["new_image"]["type"];

          if($type=="image/jpeg" || $type=="image/jpg"){
          move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
          //orginal image making part

          $imagepath = $imagename;
          $save = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
          $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file
          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ;
          $modwidth = 1000;
          $diff = $width / $modwidth;
          $modheight = $height / $diff;   
          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ;
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ;
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;
          echo "Large image: <img src='images/".$imagepath."'><br>";                     
          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;

          //thumbnail image making part
          $save = "images/thumb/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
          $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file   
          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ;
          $modwidth = 150;
          $diff = $width / $modwidth;
          $modheight = $height / $diff;
          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ;
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ;
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;
        //echo "Thumbnail: <img src='images/sml_".$imagepath."'>";
          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;
          }
        else{
            echo "File is not image";
            }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of answering years old questions with accepted answers, try answering new questions without answers

Comment: When I upload an image in size 300X200 then it converts it into 1000 width. It should convert when the image size is greater than $modwidth 1000. How can I do that?

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya you should not say like that. his answer helped me and saved my time too much

Answer (score 3):

Building onto answer from @zeusstl, for multiple images uploaded:

```
function img_resize()
{

  $input = 'input-upload-img1'; // Name of input

  $maxDim = 400;
  foreach ($_FILES[$input]['tmp_name'] as $file_name){
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file_name );
    if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
        $target_filename = $file_name;
        $ratio = $width/$height;
        if( $ratio > 1) {
            $new_width = $maxDim;
            $new_height = $maxDim/$ratio;
        } else {
            $new_width = $maxDim*$ratio;
            $new_height = $maxDim;
        }
        $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file_name ) );
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
        imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
        imagedestroy( $src );
        imagepng( $dst, $target_filename ); // adjust format as needed
        imagedestroy( $dst );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Imagick out of the box (included with most PHP distributions), it's as easy as...

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image_filehandle = fopen('some/file.jpg', 'a+');
$image->readImageFile($image_filehandle);

$image->scaleImage(100,200,FALSE);

$image_icon_filehandle = fopen('some/file-icon.jpg', 'a+');
$image->writeImageFile($image_icon_filehandle);
```

You will probably want to calculate width and height more dynamically based on the original image.  You can get an image's current width and height, using the above example, with **`$image->getImageHeight();`** and **`$image->getImageWidth();`**

Answer (score 1):

This thing worked for me.
No any external liabraries used

```
    define ("MAX_SIZE","3000");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["image-1"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image-1']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image-1']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
            echo "Unknown Extension..!";
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['image-1']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo "File Size Excedeed..!!";
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image-1']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image-1']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
echo $scr;
}

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=1000;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=1000;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


$filename = "../images/product-image/Cars/". $_FILES['image-1']['name'];

$filename1 = "../images/product-image/Cars/small". $_FILES['image-1']['name'];



imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Imagine library also. It uses GD and Imagick.

Answer (score 0):

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Image resize to upload</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <form action="pro.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if(is_array($_FILES)) {


        $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
        $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file);
        $fileNewName = time();
        $folderPath = "upload/";
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];


        switch ($imageType) {


            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. "_thump.". $ext);
                break;


            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
                break;
        }


        move_uploaded_file($file, $folderPath. $fileNewName. ".". $ext);
        echo "Image Resize Successfully.";
    }
}


function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {


    $targetWidth =200;
    $targetHeight =200;


    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);


    return $targetLayer;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!  Any explanation please with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html to produce this solution:

In my view (I am using the MVC paradigm, but it could be your `.html` or `.php` file, or the technology that you use for your front-end):

```
<form action="../../photos/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="quantity">Width:</label>
  <input type="number" id="picture_width" name="picture_width" min="10" max="800" step="1" value="500">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

My `upload.php`:

```
<?php
/* Get original image x y*/
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
$new_height=$h*$_POST['picture_width']/$w;
/* calculate new image size with ratio */
$ratio = max($_POST['picture_width']/$w, $new_height/$h);
$h = ceil($new_height / $ratio);
$x = ($w - $_POST['picture_width'] / $ratio) / 2;
$w = ceil($_POST['picture_width'] / $ratio);
/* new file name */
//$path = 'uploads/'.$_POST['picture_width'].'x'.$new_height.'_'.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$path = 'uploads/'.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
/* read binary data from image file */
$imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
/* create image from string */
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['picture_width'], $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
    0, 0,
    $x, 0,
    $_POST['picture_width'], $new_height,
    $w, $h);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        //echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($path)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    /* Save image */
    switch ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($tmp, $path);
            break;
        default:
            exit;
            break;
    }
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    /* cleanup memory */
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
?>
```

The name of the folder where pictures are stored is called 'uploads/'. You need to have that folder previously created and that is where you will see your pictures. It works great for me.

NOTE: This is my form:

[image]

The code is uploading and resizing pictures properly. I used this link as a guide: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html. I modified it because in that code they specify both width and height of resized pictures. In my case, I only wanted to specify width. The height I automatically calculated it proportionally, just keeping proper picture proportions. Everything works perfectly. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A full example with **Zebra_Image** library, that I think is so easy and useful. There are a lot of code, but if you read it, there are a lot of comments too so you can make copy and paste to use it quickly.

This example validates image format, size and replace image size with custom resolution. [There is Zebra library](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Image) and documentation (download only Zebra_Image.php file).

**Explanation**:

1. An image is uploaded to server by *uploadFile* function.
2. If image has been uploaded correctly, we recover this image and its path by *getUserFile* function.
3. Resize image to custom width and height and replace at same path.

Main function

```
private function uploadImage() {        
    $target_file = "../img/blog/";
    
//this function could be in the same PHP file or class. I use a Helper (see bellow)
    if(UsersUtils::uploadFile($target_file, $this->selectedBlog->getId())) {
//This function is at same Helper class.
//The image will be returned allways if there isn't errors uploading it, for this reason there aren't validations here.
        $blogPhotoPath = UsersUtils::getUserFile($target_file, $this->selectedBlog->getId());
        
        // create a new instance of the class
        $imageHelper = new Zebra_Image();
        // indicate a source image
        $imageHelper->source_path = $blogPhotoPath;
        // indicate a target image
        $imageHelper->target_path = $blogPhotoPath;
        // since in this example we're going to have a jpeg file, let's set the output
        // image's quality
        $imageHelper->jpeg_quality = 100;

        // some additional properties that can be set
        // read about them in the documentation
        $imageHelper->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
        $imageHelper->enlarge_smaller_images = true;
        $imageHelper->preserve_time = true;
        $imageHelper->handle_exif_orientation_tag = true;
        // resize
        // and if there is an error, show the error message
        if (!$imageHelper->resize(450, 310, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER)) {
            // if there was an error, let's see what the error is about
            switch ($imageHelper->error) {
                case 1:
                    echo 'Source file could not be found!';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo 'Source file is not readable!';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo 'Could not write target file!';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    echo 'Unsupported source file format!';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    echo 'Unsupported target file format!';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    echo 'GD library version does not support target file format!';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    echo 'GD library is not installed!';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    echo '"chmod" command is disabled via configuration!';
                    break;
                case 9:
                    echo '"exif_read_data" function is not available';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Image uploaded with new size without erros');
        }
    }
}
```

External functions or use at same PHP file removing *public static* qualifiers.

```
    public static function uploadFile($targetDir, $fileName) {        
    // File upload path
    $fileUploaded = $_FILES["input-file"];
    
    $fileType = pathinfo(basename($fileUploaded["name"]),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName .'.'.$fileType;
    
    if(empty($fileName)){
        echo 'Error: any file found inside this path';
        return false;
    }
    
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        //Max buffer length 8M
        var_dump(ob_get_length());
        if(ob_get_length() > 8388608) {
            echo 'Error: Max size available 8MB';
            return false;
        }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileUploaded["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            return true;
        }else{
            echo 'Error: error_uploading_image.';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Error: Only files JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF y PDF types are allowed';
    }
    return false;
}

public static function getUserFile($targetDir, $userId) {
    $userImages = glob($targetDir.$userId.'.*');
    return !empty($userImages) ? $userImages[0] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This class you can use with any framework or core PHP.**

For complete detail visit the below link.

https://learncodeweb.com/web-development/laravel-9-upload-multiple-files-and-image-resizer/

There are many libs that you can use to upload & resize multiple images in the Laravel. I come up with a simple and easy solution, it is a GD base class.

All you need to install via composer with the help of the below command.

```
composer require learncodeweb/filesupload
```

After installation recreates the autoload file with the help of the below command. *(optional)*

```
composer dump-autoload
```

How to import and use in the Larvel 8/9 (Tested).

```
use anyFileUpload\FilesUploadAndImageResize as anyFilesUpload;
 
$files = new anyFilesUpload('array', ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'], public_path('uploads'), 0777);
$files->uploadFiles('files', 250, '', '', 100, '850', ['350']);
 
dd($files->uploadedData);
```

After uploading files to the server, it returns all uploaded file names. You can dump those in your DB.

**Provided Functionalities**

1. Upload Single Or Multiple Files.
2. Upload Any Type Of Files (Not Only Images).
3. The image file can Resize.
4. Create Image Thumbnails (With Keep The Image Aspect Ratio).
5. You can add a watermark (Text, Image).
6. Easy Integration With Forms.
7. Create Any Number Of Thumbnails Under One Upload.
8. Customizable Paths To Thumbnails Folders.
9. Customizable Thumbnails Sizes And Dimensions.
10. Files Extension Filters.
11. File Size Limit for Uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Based on zeusstl soulution you can add this to 4th line if you want that either of width or height use maxDim and highest measure is set based on this:

```
if ($height > $width) {
    $maxDim = $maxDim * ($height/$width);
} else {
    $maxDim = $maxDim * ($width/$height);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Download library file Zebra_Image.php belo link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx-7K3oajNTRV1I2UzYySGZFd3M/view

resizeimage.php

```
<?php
    require 'Zebra_Image.php';
    // create a new instance of the class
     $resize_image = new Zebra_Image();
     // indicate a source image
    $resize_image->source_path = $target_file1;
    $ext = $photo;
    // indicate a target image
    $resize_image->target_path = 'images/thumbnil/' . $ext;
    // resize
    // and if there is an error, show the error message
    if (!$resize_image->resize(200, 200, ZEBRA_IMAGE_NOT_BOXED, -1));
    // from this moment on, work on the resized image
    $resize_image->source_path = 'images/thumbnil/' . $ext;
?>
```

Comment: This comment is uncomplete... There are some variables without initialization, like $photo or $target_file1;