# resize image while uploading in PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading, resize-image

I have a file upload form where I upload only jpg, png and gif images. I resize the image if its width is more then 225 and height automatically fix with that width.

```
if($width > 225) {
    $newwidth = 225;
} 
else {
    $newwidth = $width; 
}
$newheight = ($height/$width)*$newwidth;
```

The above code fixes the width for me in case if `image > 225`. Now the problem is that the new height is according to the image width. I don't want the `height` to be more then `150`. How can I fix it with out stretching the image?

Comment: Resize the height the same value you resize the width. If height is still >150 then resize both again.

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Hi try to below link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805497/php-resize-image-on-upload/39386636#39386636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting the width in case of `$newheight` being greater than 150, calculating the proportion. Add this at the bottom:

```
if ($newheight > 150) {
    $proportion = $newwidth/$newheight;
    $newheight = 150;
    $newwidth = 150*$proportion;
}
```