# Resize an image setting min width and max height

Tags: php, css, image, image-processing

I am using ImageMagick with PHP to resize images (using its commandline tool "convert").

I am able to resize images and everything works.

What I want to do is I want to resize an image (of any dimension) to an image setting the minimum width and maximum height and at the same time preserve the image resolution/aspect ratio. How do I do this?

**Why I want this:** I am putting these images in a news feed in my website where I require images to be of width:100% but the problem is height becomes too large for certain images and occupies an entire page. I want to avoid it.

This is what I am using for resize:

```
$cmd="convert -thumbnail ".$width."x".$height." \"".$source."\" \"".$dest."\";";
```

Comment: If you're already using PHP, why are you doing raw command lines?  There's an API for Imagick in PHP.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805497/php-resize-image-on-upload/40324941#40324941

Answer (score 0):

You can find the resize options on the Imagemagick website: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

I do not think these will achieve what you want so I would check the dimensions of your image and calculate the height to go with your width which you can use in your convert code.