# Upload, Resize and Rename an Image with PHP

Tags: php

how do rename an image file and then upload with resize image see below my php code

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], "bannerimg/" . $image);
        $image = new SimpleImage();
        $image->load("bannerimg/" . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
        $image->resize(520,310);
        $image->save("bannerimg/thumbs/" . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
```

Comment: This question has already been answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805497/php-resize-image-on-upload

Comment: can you help me on my given code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple? This one does exactly what you want: [PHP rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```
rename($_FILES["img"]["name"], "new_name.jpg");
```

And here you go, then you may do whatever you want. :)