# Resize and crop image to a fixed size in php

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I know there are lot of questions asked on this topic and have many grate answers. But non of those didn't worked for me.
I my e-commerce website product images are 1025X1400. I need to resize any image to 1025X1400 when uploading a product image. If the selected image dimensions are less than 1025X1400 i need to add background color, without loosing aspect ratio. Like below

[This is the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIUQG.png)

I followed this question, and it worked, but it stretch the image.
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27213444/8368946)

How can i do this in PHP.
Thank you

***Edit***
I don't need to check the dimensions. I need to save uploaded images, after resizing(1025X1400).

Comment: javascript will do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to check the image size with javascript/jquery and add background color with an if statement to it. You dont need PHP for this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP library to resize, scale and crop images.
https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize